# I tried to build something, but this error came and I couldn't get SW also

Tags: cmake, makefile, leptonica

```
 By not providing "FindSW.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has asked
  CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "SW", but CMake did
  not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "SW" with any of
  the following names:

    SWConfig.cmake
    sw-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "SW" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "SW_DIR" to
  a directory containing one of the above files.  If "SW" provides a separate
  development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.
```

What I am trying to build is leptonica, but I can't do it without having there .cmake files, and I have no idea how I can get them, since I couldn't build SW.

Comment: what do you mean by "wintout having their CMake files"? It seems like you can find them [on github](https://github.com/danbloomberg/leptonica). See this thread for discussion on [windows setup with SW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60968901/leptonica-on-windows-visual-studio). If it helps, this question could possibly be marked as a duplicate.

Comment: so was that thread able to help you solve your problem? Is it okay for me to flag this as a duplicate?